# Identify the position of the noun that the adjective modifies

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I found this sentence in a thesis that you can find [here](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/45882):

> How do people learn abstract concepts unsupervised?

I sounds strange to me since *unsupervised* is an adjective (and from popular dictionaries, adjective is the only class for this word) but the noun it's modifying seem to be absent from the sentence.

My best guess here is that *unsupervised* may be used to modify some "hidden" noun phrase (rather than *people*) that I'm unaware of. Please help to point it out.

Comment: It's a reduced clause with a participial predicate; it means _How do people learn abstract concepts (when/while/although they are) unsupervised?_

Comment: @JohnLawler By using "they" in your sentence, did you mean "people" or "abstract concepts"?

Comment: I meant _people_ but it's actually  ambiguous, whether it's deleted or not.  All written sentences are multiply ambiguous because writing doesn't include intonation.

Comment: It's interesting because it seems to work with some adjectives but not others. A similar sentence might be "I don't know how to sail a boat single-handed." It might also be related to constructions such as "drive drunk" where you have an adjective and a verb in a close relationship. In each case the adjective describes the manner of doing something or the state of the person while doing the thing. (I thought there was already a question about "drive drunk" but I can't see it.)

Comment: *How do people learn abstract concepts [**when those people are**] unsupervised?* *How do people learn abstract concepts [**when those abstract concepts are**] as-yet-undefined?* It makes no sense to talk about "abstract concepts" being "unsupervised" (but they could certainly be "as-yet-undefined"). And as pointed out by others, there's nothing about the English language itself that rules out such an interpretation.

Comment: Why must it modify a noun? It seems to me it describes *learn*.

Comment: @Xanne because it's an adjective as most popular dictionaries show that. But if it describe "learn" (as the verb) then it should be an adverb, but again I found no dictionary that lists this word as an adverb.

Comment: @KhanhTran "Unsupervised" is an adjective here functioning as a predicative adjunct. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "people", and it's an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure, i.e. in the verb phrase. If that makes sense to you, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Flip it around: "How do unsupervised people learn abstract concepts?" However, I agree that when you put it at the end, it seems to be modifying the process of learning, not the people. So "How do people learn abstract concepts [while] unsupervised"

Comment: @BillJ Based on my understanding on (un)supervised learning, the term focuses on the learning process rather than the learner. For example, the learner will be provided with feedback for what they've learnt constantly (or partially) through the learning process (in case of supervised learning) while they, themself, may or may not be supervised. So for example, if they, themself, are SUPERVISED (like we put a camera directly towards them) but they're NOT provided with any feedback during learning, we still say that their learning is UNsupervised. (to be continue)

Comment: Also @Barmar, Based on my own comment above, then the sentence "How do unsupervised people learn abstract concepts?" seems to have a complete different meaning with the original one. Besides, if "unsupervised" is meant to modify the meaning of the learning process, then it should be an adverb right (because "learn" is a verb)?

Comment: @KhanhTran It's the people who are unsupervised.

Comment: @KhanhTran It's not uncommon to use adjectives adverbally. "unsupervisedly" is cumbersome

Comment: @Xanne 'He shot the man dead' obviously has 'dead' describing the (resultative, final) state of whoever 'the man' is referring to. It doesn't, in the first instance, refer to the manner of shooting (deliberately? carelessly?), or comment on the horror (sadly? unforgivably?), so it's better construed as an adjective here. 'She hammered the metal _flat_' likewise is agreed to use the _resultative construction_ (adjective). I've seen 'Shearer shot wide' analysed as being indeterminate: is Shearer's shooting manner or the result being highlighted? But most would say 'unsupervised' here is an adj.

Answer (score 1):

> *How do people learn abstract concepts unsupervised?*

"Unsupervised" is an adjective here functioning as a predicative adjunct.

It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "people", and it's an adjunct because it's a modifier, not in NP structure, but in clause structure, i.e. in the verb phrase.

It is of course depictive in that it gives descriptive information about "people".

Comment: I agree that "unsupervised" is an adjective, what I'm still reluctant to agree is the part that says "it gives information about people". Cause as I commented in the question section, it should give information about the learning process rather than people. And it's perfectly fine to be an adject since a verb (even not copulative) can take an adjective as it's compliment to describe changes to the state of things (I was unaware of this thing before). Sources: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/go?q=Go - https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern/v-adj_15